# jquery element.style issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
    (function($) {

$.widget("ui.selectmenu", {
  getter: "value",
  version: "1.8",
  eventPrefix: "selectmenu",
  options: {
    transferClasses: true,
    typeAhead: "sequential",
    style: 'dropdown',
    positionOptions: {
      my: "left top",
      at: "left bottom",
      offset: null
    },
    width: null,
    menuWidth: null,
    handleWidth: 26,
    maxHeight: null,
    icons: null,
    format: null,
    bgImage: function() {},
    wrapperElement: "<div />"
  },

  _create: function() {
    var self = this, o = this.options;

    // set a default id value, generate a new random one if not set by developer
    var selectmenuId = this.element.attr( 'id' ) || 'ui-selectmenu-' + Math.random().toString( 16 ).slice( 2, 10 );

    // quick array of button and menu id's
    this.ids = [ selectmenuId + '-button', selectmenuId + '-menu' ];

    // define safe mouseup for future toggling
    this._safemouseup = true;

    // create menu button wrapper
    this.newelement = $( '<a />', {
      'class': this.widgetBaseClass + ' ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all',
      'id' : this.ids[ 0 ],
      'role': 'button',
      'href': '#',
      'tabindex': this.element.attr( 'disabled' ) ? 1 : 0,
      'aria-haspopup': true,
      'aria-owns': this.ids[ 1 ]
    });
    this.newelementWrap = $( o.wrapperElement )
      .append( this.newelement )
      .insertAfter( this.element );

    // transfer tabindex
    var tabindex = this.element.attr( 'tabindex' );
    if ( tabindex ) {
      this.newelement.attr( 'tabindex', tabindex );
    }

    // save reference to select in data for ease in calling methods
    this.newelement.data( 'selectelement', this.element );
```

in this create function dynamically width is coming as per the browser standards for only menu. so now i want to remove the width property for menu please give a solution on it.

and also please check the following code for see how it displayed in fire bug.. it's dynamically creating the inline style width showing as in element.style{}

```
<a class="ui-selectmenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-selectmenu-dropdown tinydrop tradedrop ui-state-active ui-corner-top" id="ui-selectmenu-3cab43ef-button" role="button" href="#" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="ui-selectmenu-3cab43ef-menu" style="width: 97px; " aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-selectmenu-status">Buy</span><span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if the width is not dynamic , You have to manually set styles for the browser , for example see this ??

Here the background-color value  will be set as per the browser .

```
<style type="text/css">
.ie .example {
  background-color: yellow
}
.ie7 .example {
  background-color: orange
}
.opera .example {
  background-color: green
}
.konqueror .example {
  background-color: blue
}
.webkit .example {
  background-color: black
}
</style>
```

Comment: this width not static but it would be dynamically so your code will not work.